# Low resolution problem during rendering a particle

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, smoke-simulation, emission, resolution

i made an simple explosion simulation for creating sprite sheet to my game.
but when i start to render animation at 1920x1080 resolution, explosion still looks low quality.
Here is an example:[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your gas domain needs a higher resolution.

[image]